# Stripe integration with Apple Pay

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, applepay

Sorry if this is a more generalized question, but I am hoping to get some understanding before I pay over $100 for an Apple developer membership.

I am working on Stripe.js integration as payment method for my website. Specifically, I am using the Stripe Web Elements(https://stripe.com/docs/payments/elements) and want to enable the Apple pay option there.

I followed the requirement per Stripe doc at https://support.stripe.com/questions/enable-apple-pay-on-your-stripe-account, and verified my domain with the "apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association" file.

Then the final step 6, it asks me to continue with integrating Apple Pay for the Web following Apple Pay's documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web

This is where things got confusing for me. The Apple Pay documentation talks about all these different steps, such as:

1. Create a merchant identifier:
   https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/configure-apple-pay#create-a-merchant-identifier
2. Create a payment processing certificate:
   https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/configure-apple-pay#create-a-payment-processing-certificate
3. Register a merchant domain
   https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/configure-apple-pay-on-the-web#register-a-merchant-domain
4. Using the Apple Pay JS API or the Payment Request API
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/payment_request_api
5. "Complete merchant validation" via my server
   https://applepaydemo.apple.com/payment-request-api

I understand that not all of the above instructions apply for Stripe integration, such as step 4 and 5.
But I am not sure which other steps are necessary and which are handled by Stripe.

Can anyone please help clarify, or point me to a good resource/implementation?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as your domain verified by Apple and serve your site through HTTPS, your website is ready to accept Apple Pay payments. The requirements are clearer in this Stripe integration [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#apple-pay-and-google-pay).